# Не отключать дисплей при блокировке смартфона

Tags: java, android

Можно ли в приложении сделать следующую функцию: запускаем наше приложение, сворачиваем его, запускаем допустим видео, блокируем экран, и смотрим фильм дальше. Вопрос:

Как это можно реализовать?

Спасиб.